# Why does this output 19?

Tags: php

It is not clear the logic behind this PHP code to give out the answer 19. How can the answer be 19? What is the logic?

```
$i=5;
$i +=$i++ + ++$i;
echo $i;
```

Comment: where is the code????

Comment: There is also no reason for this to be tagged with Java or HTML5

Comment: PHP questions should be tagged with php not Java

Comment: $i = $i++ //5    additional 1 will take effect next call
++$i //7   :: $i = 6 2nd call, ++$i will take effect immediately $i = 7
$i += is the same as $i = $i + $i
$i = 7 + 12 = 19

Answer (score 10):

```
$i=5;
$i +=$i++ + ++$i;
     ^
     Take value of $i as 5 then increment to 6
              ^
              increment value of $i from 6 to 7, and use the 7
          ^
          5 + 7 = 12
   ^ $i is already 7, because of the increments in the previous operations,
     so add the 12 we've just calculated, giving 19
```

Comment: I was always wondering what's the point in "expressions" like OP posted in questions. Neither practical, nor theoretical value. Just "brain-teasing". Anyways, good catch

Answer (score 2):

First, let's consider the following code:

```
<?php

$e = 0;
$e += ++$e;
echo $e;
```

Will the output be `2`, or will it be `1`?

One the second line, the right hand side of the equation `++$e;` will increment the value of `$e`, making `$e` (temporarily) equal 1.

When the left hand side of the equation is run, `$e` equals `1` already, so `1` will be added the that value, so essentially, the line really says `$e = 1 + 1`.

```
<?php

$e = 0;
$e = 1 + 1;
echo $e;
```

When we do the same with the equation given earlier,

```
$i=5;
$i +=$i++ + ++$i;
echo $i;
```

The importance here is post and pre incrementing.

- `++i` increments i and evaluates to the new value of i.
- `i++` evaluates to the old value of i, and increments i.

When `$i += $i++ + ++$i;` is calculated, on the Right Hand Side, `++$i` (which will be 5) and `$i++` (which will be 7).

`$i += 5 + 7` (which becomes `7 + 5 + 7`) means that `$i` will equal `19`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$i += $i++ + ++$i ; 
$i = $i + ($i+1 + 1+$i);
19 = 7 + (5 + 7);
```

Comment: Mixing pre-increment and post-increment within expressions is a minefield in most languages because it modifies `$i`. Can you back your interpretation up with language references that explain the sequence of modification of `$i` and the associativity please?